How to multihop swap with Uniswap V2/V3 without transfering back and forth intermediary tokens to caller?
In the case of multihop swap on Uniswap, it is convenient that pools send the output token prior to calling the swap callback. 
It allows to pay the first pool with the output of the last pool without having, prior to this, the input amount of the first pool. 
By cascading : uniswap callbacks with calls to pool's swap method.
caller contract
  ⤷ P0 swap
     ⤷ caller cb
         ⤷ P1 swap
            ⤷ caller cb
                ⤷ P2 swap
                  ⤷ caller cb --(send back input token)--> P0

with :

Pi swap := pool n°i swap method
caller cb := contract callback

But it seems impossible to do multihop swap without transfering back intermediary tokens to calling contract, is it really the case ?
UniswapV2Pair
In this case, it is possible to transfer the input token before calling the swap() method. 
This is thanks to the K constant testing at the end of the swap :
require(balance0Adjusted.mul(balance1Adjusted) >= uint(_reserve0).mul(_reserve1).mul(1000**2), 'UniswapV2: K');

But it is impossible to set a recipient different from msg.sender (to is the contracts's callback address and the recipient) :
if (amount0Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
if (amount1Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token1, to, amount1Out); // optimistically transfer tokens

UniswapV3Pool
In this case, it is impossible to send the input token prior to calling the swap() method. 
Because of the check of the delta balance just before and after calling the callback.
uint256 balance0Before = balance0();
IUniswapV3SwapCallback(msg.sender).uniswapV3SwapCallback(amount0, amount1, data);
require(balance0Before.add(uint256(amount0)) <= balance0(), 'IIA');

Contrary to V2Pairs, it is possible to set a recipient different from msg.sender but still call msg.sender callback.

Being able to forward the output token directly to the next pool's input would allow to save on ERC20 transfers thus reducing gas cost.
Have I understood well, that this is indeed impossible to do ? 
If so, do you know if there is a reason why it has been implemented in this fashion ?
